# convert object of class into string

Tags: php

```
class Person
{
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;    
    }
}

class Business
{
    protected $staff; 

    public function __construct(Staff $staff) 
    {
        $this->staff = $staff;
    }

    public function hire(Person $person)
    {
        $this->staff->add($person); 
    }

    public function getStaffMembers()
    {
        return $this->staff->members();
    }


}


class Staff //staff é uma coleção, logo os membros são um array
{
    protected $members = []; 

    public function __construct($members = [])
    {
        $this->members = $members;
    }
    public function add(Person $person)
    {
        $this->members[] = $person; 
    }   
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->members;
    }   
}

$daniel = new Person('Daniel Santos'); //name==$daniel santos

$staff = new Staff([$daniel]);  

$laracasts = new Business($staff); 

$laracasts->hire(new Person("Jorge")); 

var_dump($laracasts->getStaffMembers());
```

I would like to `print(implode("",$laracasts->getStaffMembers());` instead of just `var_dump()` it. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to be able to print an object, you'll need to add a `__toString` method to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [`__toString` "magic method"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) to your `Person` class.

```
class Person
{
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

`__toString` provides a string representation of the class, so you can use it in string contexts, like `echo $person`, or `echo implode(', ', $laracasts->getStaffMembers());`

In this example I just returned the person's name, but you can do more complex stuff in that method as well (formatting, etc.), as long as it returns a string.

Comment: After your answer i did some research and i just added the __tostring method to the Staff class, because i thought the members had to be converted into a string. Thanks a lot.